# How to check a function was called with a spefic argument python

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, pytest

I am writing a unit test and I am trying to check that function was called with the right arguments. I was told that I can do this with mocking. This is my code

```
import pytest
from mock import patch
import attr

def adjust(x):
    if x is None:
        return 0
    return x

@attr.s
class Pater():
    only_argument = attr.ib(type=int,converter = adjust)

def foo(pass_only):
    yield Pater(pass_only)

@patch("this_file.Pater")
def test_foo(mock_Pater):
    foo(None)
    mock_Pater.assert_called_with(None)
```

But I am getting the following error

```
E           AssertionError: expected call not found.
E           Expected: Pater(None)
E           Actual: not called.
```

Could you advise me on how to do it correctly?

Answer (score 2):

Your test does not, indeed, call/instantiate `Pater`, because `foo()` is a `Pater` generator, and you haven't pulled any items from it yet.  To put it another way, the code inside the `yield` isn't executed until you iterate over the return value of `foo()`.

Change your test to:

```
@patch("this_file.Pater")
def test_foo(mock_Pater):
    next(foo(None))
    mock_Pater.assert_called_with(None)
```

and it will pass.